# Apache OpenNLP Name Entity Finder identifing wrong words

Tags: java, opennlp

I'm trying to use Apache OpenNLP to identify date entities in a text. I created a little java program that generates a tag using a range of dates in the following format:

```
<START:date> {dd/MM/yyyy} <END> .
```

Each tag is a sentence in the format defined by OpenNLP.

I generated approximately 400k entries and trained the model. After the training, I tried to use **TokenNameFinder** by command line to verify if everything was ok but for every word, I typed the finder identified it as the dated entity. For example, when I typed:

```
today is 17/04/2017
```

what i got was:

```
<START:date> today <END> <START:date> is <END> <START:date> 17/04/2017 <END>
```

I thought it could be that I didn't provide it any word except the dates so I tried to use a random string before and after the tag but the training time was taking forever.

Can anyone tell me if this is a problem with my training dataset or anything else I must be doing?

Comment: Can you provide a small snippet of the training data? Also, copy the command line or the code you used for the training. Tks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To train a machine learning Name Finder model you would need a training corpus as close as possible to the runtime data. If your dates are well behaved and you don't need machine learning, you can try the regex based one [RegexNameFinder](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.7.2/apidocs/opennlp-tools/opennlp/tools/namefind/RegexNameFinder.html).

If training is taking forever, either it is too big or you have few empty lines to mark the end of a document. Refer to the [Named Entity Recognition](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.7.2/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind.recognition) documentation for details.

Comment: +1 to using the RegexNameFinder for dates (due to their "well-behaved" format :). Alternatively, you can look into using https://github.com/HeidelTime/heideltime